# Ruby Rspec, 'Let' not being accepted as available within example group Rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, scope

I'm having some trouble with Rspec accepting the scope of one of my `let` definitions.

Here's my test, the classes all work fine as when I have them print out they're sweet.

```
code removed due to silly error
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `do` and `end` for your `it` block:

```
    describe "Initialisation of order within User object" do
      it "Creates an order property set to an empty array" do
        expect(user.instance_variable_defined?(:@orders)).to be(true)
        expect(user.instance_variable_get(:@orders)).to eq([])
      end
    end
```

Comment: :|  ...        I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Thanks @pixelearth, you're the best

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted ;)